# Write a program to compute the following Quadratic Equation:

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the following program for the equation `b+-b^2-4*a*c/2a`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float x1,x2,x3,b,a,c;
    cout<<"Enter the value of \"a\",\"b\",\"c\""<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    x3=pow(b,2);
    x1=(-1*b+sqrt(x3-4*a*c))/2*a;
    x2=(-1*b-sqrt(x3-4*a*c))/2*a;
    cout<<"The answer for the first equation is:"<<x1<<endl;
    cout<<"The answer for the second equation is:"<<x2<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the value of "a","b","c":

2

2

2

The answer of the first equation is : NaN

The answer of the second equation is: NaN
```

Why is the output `NaN`?

Comment: Learn how to help yourself: Print the intermediate values, then the parts of the equations. See where the result does not match your expectation and limit the scope of your question to this. Then read up the documentation of the function that is giving you NaN. Also: The formula you have shown in the text is not the formula that is calculated in the program.

Comment: Have you determined that `2x^2 + 2x + 2 = 0` actually has any real roots?

Comment: The formula calculated in the program is also not the formula to solve quadratic equations with real roots. And somehow I think x*x is simpler than pow (x, 2).

Comment: I am a student at a university and there we are doing pow instead of x*x but thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x3(4)-4*a*c(4*2*2=16) = -12 is a negative number so sqrt() returns nan

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and I will try to get a positive answer that Nan doesn't come again.